# Is Marcus Tremaine based on Cinderella's father from any of the movies?

Tags: character, once-upon-a-time, cinderella-2015, cinderella-1950

He is Anastasia and Drizella's father, like Francis Tremaine, but he was like a father to Cinderella.

On the [Disney Wiki](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Sir_Francis_Tremaine), he is on the Sir Francis Tremaine page, but on the [Once Upon A Time Wiki](https://onceuponatime.fandom.com/wiki/Marcus_Tremaine), it just says he's based on Cinderella's father.

So is he based on the father's character from one of the Cinderella movies? If so, which movie?

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was closed as an opinion-based question? It's asking for a very specific reference of a similar character between 2 or 3 works, all of which are "Disney" property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Once Upon A Time* took a spin on western literary classics and folklore, but also, in many cases, referencing Disney's animated works, which are also adaptations in and of themselves. Disney owns ABC, which was the network of *Once Upon A Time*.

> [*Once Upon A Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_(TV_series)) is an American fantasy drama television series
>   on ABC which **debuted on October 23, 2011**, and concluded on May 18,
>   2018. The first six seasons are largely set in the fictitious seaside town of Storybrooke, Maine, with the character of Emma Swan as the
>   lead, while the seventh and final season takes place in Seattle,
>   Washington, in the fictitious neighborhood of Hyperion Heights, with a
>   new main narrative led by Henry Mills, Emma Swan and Regina Mills's
>   son. **The show borrows elements and characters from the Disney
>   universe** and popular Western literature, folklore, and fairy tales.

Therefore many characters, such as Snow White, Belle, Ariel, and Cinderella, tend to look similar to their iconic Disney animated counterparts and include variations of other characters that may also be a part of Disney's and/or any of the original work's story.

However, this question becomes a bit more complicated, because it relates to the **second iteration** of "fairytale characters" where Cinderella is no longer "Ashley", but rather Jacinda, who is visually a contrast to the iconic Disney princess and basically retells and re-spins *'Once's'* original Cinderella story.

> [*Cinderella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_(2015_Disney_film)) is a **2015** romantic fantasy film directed by
>   Kenneth Branagh, with a screenplay written by Chris Weitz, and
>   **co-produced by Walt Disney Pictures**, Kinberg Genre, Allison Shearmur Productions, and Beagle Pug Films. The film is based on the
>   eponymous folk tale and **is a live action adaptation of Walt Disney's
>   1950 animated film of the same name.**[6] It features Lily James as
>   the eponymous character, with Cate Blanchett, Richard Madden, Stellan
>   Skarsgård, Holliday Grainger, Derek Jacobi, and Helena Bonham Carter.

*Cinderella (2015)* is one of Disney's new live-action and/or photo-real adaptations of their own animated source material and came out in the middle of *Once Upon A Time's* run.

I have not found any source that tells me that the writers & executive producers of *'Once'* ever discussed anything with the 2015 feature film's writers and executive producers to prove if the 2015 film had any influence on the *'Once'* character, but at the very least both were inspired by the 1950's animated classic.

In addition Sir Francis is only ever mentioned in the 2015 film and is not a well-formed character in his own right, meaning that the plot of him being a potential step father to "Cinderella" is the only idea that could taken from this film.

However, [Marcus Tremaine](https://onceuponatime.fandom.com/wiki/Marcus_Tremaine) also was **an allusion to Rapunzel's prince (Grim Bros. Fairytale) and/or Finn Ryder** from [Tangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangled) and therefore is a character that is a bit more than just playing homage to Cinderella's "father figure" by bridging two fairy tale families together...